# Release size of SVN Repository on Linux Server

Tags: apache, svn, centos5

We are using following build/version of SVN.

```
svn, version 1.6.11 (r934486) compiled Apr 11 2013, 14:29:11.
Copyright (C) 2000-2009 CollabNet.
Subversion is open source software, see http://subversion.tigris.org/
This product includes software developed by CollabNet (http://www.Collab.Net/).
```

We have configured SVN on http on `Apache 2.2 on CentOS release 5.10 (Final)`
We are using 4 main source code repositories. One of the Repository size has gone more than 70GB. Some of the repository branches merging is pending.
In past we have been cleaning SVN By:

- Completing pending merging of all branches.
- Then exporting the Repository source code.
- Checking Out source code.
- Committing the source code.

But by doing this we loose all the previous commits history, comments, revision numbers etc.

**Our question is:**

> Is there a way that we delete some branches in the repository and
>   reclaim its size on the server?

Typical structure of SVN repository is:

- http://db4.coplsaas.com.au/svn/insurance/clients/client1/production
- http://db4.coplsaas.com.au/svn/insurance/clients/client1/development
- http://db4.coplsaas.com.au/svn/insurance/clients/client1/releases
- http://db4.coplsaas.com.au/svn/insurance/clients/client1/branches

Same structure is for other clients( say client2, client3, client4 etc ).
We want to remove all folders in "releases" and some folders in "branches" and its sub-folders from every client repository folders.

Please advise.

Comment: Your links are returning 404.

Comment: IVan, these were just sample repository Urls to explain sub folder structure under main repository folders.

Answer (score 2):

According to the FAQ below either of these approaches should work:

1. svnadmin dump your repository, then pipe the dumpfile through svndumpfilter (to remove what you want) then into an svnadmin load command to load into a fresh repository.
2. replicate the repository with svnsync after configuring path-based authorization rules that deny read access to any paths that need to be filtered from history.

http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#removal